Consulta sobre classes en c++
Estoy repasando para un parcial de C++ y los profesores nos dieron unos ejercicios de ejemplo con sus resultados.
Esta es la primera vez que veo que una Clase puede ser usada como tipo de Vector, así que lo intenté y me está dando error.
Yo solamente quiero saber si es posible usar una Clase para definir un Vector o mis profesores le erraron.
Abajo dejo el código que dieron mis profesores como resultado.
class Pasajero {
    string m_apenom;
    bool m_1ra_clase;
    float m_equipaje;
public:
    Pasajero(string apenom, string pasaporte, bool es_1ra_clase, float equipaje)
        : m_apenom(apenom), m_1ra_clase(es_1ra_clase), m_equipaje(equipaje) { }
    string ApellidoYNombre() { return m_apenom; }
    bool EsPrimeraClase() { return m_1ra_clase; }
    float PesoEquipaje() { return m_equipaje; }
};

class Vuelo {
    string m_origen, m_destino;
    int m_lugares_estandar, m_lugares_1ra_clase;
    vector<Pasajero> m_pasajeros;
public:
    Vuelo(string origen, string destino, int n_estandar, int n_1ra_clase)
        : m_origen(origen), m_destino(destino),
        m_lugares_estandar(n_estandar), m_lugares_1ra_clase(n_1ra_clase) { }


Ese codigo esta perfecto.. tu duda es si un vector puede contener otra cosa que no sea un numero?? y si... puede contener cualquier cosa...

Por supuesto que puedes usar una clase o estructura "cualquiera" como tipo de un vector, igual que con clases de la stdlib, como std:string. Simplemente la clase deberá cumplir ciertos requisitos, principalmente marcados por las operaciones que realizes con ese vector. Un ejemplo absurdo: https://godbolt.org/z/85fMxG41q Si tienes errores al usar el ejemplo que muestras u otro código similar el error no está en intentar usar una clase "propia" como tipo del vector, seguramente estarás cometiendo algún error en el uso del mismo, intentas usar operaciones que tu clase no soporta/implementa, etc

No veo ningún error en un tu código. A menos que tengas otra duda, tu pregunta se puede responder con un simple "sí". Al igual que en otros lenguajes, puedes tener listas de cualquier tipo de elemento. Siempre y cuando cumpla con los requisitos de CopyAssignable y CopyConstructible. Para más información, mira la documentación.

Tu código tal y como lo publicas da error porque faltan includes (vector y string) y falta }; al final de la clase Vuelo.

El código esta perfecto pero falta }; para la clase vuelo,
por otro lado tu puedes crear un vector (array unidimensional) de cualquier tipo de dato preexistente o creado por ti, al final solo es un bloque de memoria que se preasigna y puede ser accedido mediante un índice.
Esto aplica también para colecciones no indexadas como listas, pueden contener cualquier tipo de dato.
